# The verb "to overlook" embraces the opposite meanings?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

One of the meanings of the verb **to overlook** is "to provide a view of" (*the chateau overlooks fields of olive trees*), when it **gives you** the possibility of seeing. The other meaning is "to fail to notice," (*I have overlooked the key fact*), when you **lack** the possibility of seeing.

How can one term include two opposite meanings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is my analysis, surely I may be wrong.)

Interestingly, there is no contradiction if we consider the real physical meaning of this verb—"**to see above**." When you say "*I could overlook the whole village from my window*," it means you **could see above** the buildings, trees and other structures in the village. It actually does not say that you could see the structures themselves, but **we imply that**—if you could see above something you could see the object itself.

So now this meaning does not contradict with the second—"*I have overlooked his car in the road*," which means I was **looking above** the car, and that's why I didn't see it.